# Setting values to a form which is not rendered yet

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a form within a tab. It is second tab so it doesn't render until you open it.

I have tried to submit data to the form with `Ext.getCmp('DetailsForm').getForm().setValues(selections[0]);` but it says that it is not a function. Probably because it is not rendered yet. What I have to do?

Comment: Tabpanel's [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-items) clearly mention the lazy rendering issue, also something about doLayout(), but I doubt it will solve your issue. I have a system where a record selected on the left side of the screen need to be loaded to the various tabs on the right. Whenever the record is selected i keep a reference to it, and whenever my tabpanel shoots `activate` I refer to that record.

Comment: @Izhaki You should take a look at the [deferredRender](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-deferredRender) property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [deferredRender](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-deferredRender) config property of your Ext.tab.Panel to `deferredRender: false`

That will force the rendering of all tabs instead of just active ones. Now the form will be there. As mentioned before I recommend you also to use myTabPanelRef.down('from').getForm().setValues(selections[0]); to access the form.

Answer (score 0):

subscribe to the second tabs `show` event OR `painted` event
then look for the form preferably by using `.down()` method as this wont look with in the entire DOM.
set the values

Answer (score 0):

Use **render** event of form panel. 
Your code will be something like this -

`Ext.getCmp('DetailsForm').on('render', function(){
    this.getForm().load(selections[0]);
});`